# AR development Library in Android

Tags: android, library, java, sdk, vr

I'm new to AR (I have experience in VR though), and want to do some simple AR development (detect traffic signs printed on papers). Are there any simple-to-use library or SDK for AR development?

I'm a java guy myself, so I want it to be Android, no native/NDK development.

Comment: Define your acronyms. I tried to do so for you but system refused my edit.